# How to make WebStorm (or any IDE) warn on calling methods not defined in module?

Tags: javascript, ide, webstorm, static-code-analysis

This is the problem in its simplest form:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var module1 = {
      someMethod: function(a) {}
  };

  var module2 = {
      anotherMethod: function(b) {}
  };

  module2.someMethod();
})();
```

WebStorm (or any other IDE I've tried for that matter) sees no problem with that code. It finds `someMethod` declaration in `module1`, it even warns about incorrect number of parameters passed to it, but it doesn't warn, that `module2` has no method `someMethod`. Now, I know that JS is dynamic, and it is very possible to modify modules prototypes and add these methods in runtime, but is there any way to analyse such things statically to prevent runtime errors (without rewriting the whole project in TypeScript, or something like that)?
Note, that the above code is for illustration purposes only, in real life those are AMD modules with many methods and props, loaded with requirejs, but the problem is exactly the same.

Comment: It would probably be too difficult to determine whether or not it's impossible for a module to contain a certain method. I've never seen an IDE give compile-time errors/warnings about this.

Comment: Maybe Flow can do this; I'm not familiar enough with it. But dynamic languages are notoriously difficult to police like this.

Comment: @DaveNewton, thanks will check how Flow can help with these type of errors.

Comment: @Carcigenicate sure, but maybe some top-level inspection, turned off by default)